# Is there a word or term other than ‘exemplar’ for the educational cards used to teach English?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a word or term other than ‘exemplar’ for the educational cards used in primary classrooms to teach English? These are the:

> 'A' is for 'Apple'

Or for the cards which show how to write a letterform which tends to line the walls of some classrooms.

> 'A' 'a', 'B' 'b', etcetera

I am looking for a general use term or phrase which elementary teachers would refer to these and not for product names used to purchase them.

Comment: Are you looking for another adjective, or the product name?

Comment: Sorry, not looking to buy them, just curious as to what they’re normally called. Were it a book or journal I would assume ‘exemplar’. I’m uncertain if grade-school teachers use a different term. Will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [teaching catalog](http://teachingkinders.com/pricing.html), these are called wall cards:

[image]

This other [website](http://www.notepolish.com/item/Vintage-Alphabet-Wall-Cards/255), which sells them as vintage, also refers to the following as wall cards:

[image]

Finally, here's a wall card that shows the letterform:

[image]

Another option, which seems to fit the original idea you posted, are **alphabet lines:**

[image]

Comment: +1 Thank you, I'll use that if no one has an alternative one I'll prefer.

Comment: Edited -- I found something which may fit better.

Comment: Alphabet lines could work as it helps convey a sort of homey anachronism also present in the story. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Flash cards? Those are generally the size of cue cards or notecards, though, so I am not sure if you mean something larger.

Comment: Sorry, not flashcards. It may be a US centric experience. It may also be a practice which has fallen out of favour. I found this image which is instead for numbers http://www.bc.k12.mi.us/images/ELimages/BldgTour/kroom2.jpg. This one is a sort of homemade one (though lacks the arrows I remember on how to draw the letterforms: http://www.progressivepreschool.org/images/Writing%20table.jpg